# Joomla - posting pictures

Tags: php, html, joomla, mysqli

I am trying to post pictures in a joomla page. I am completely new in php and joomla.

This is what I have in a joomla page:

```
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<p><img src="images/test.php?id=8" alt="powered by" />
</p>
<p>Done!</p>
```

this is test.php:

```
<?php

$link=...... //connection to database
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query=... 
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query); 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $imageData = $row['photo'];
    }
    header("content-type: image/png");
    echo $imageData;
}
?>
```

This is just for a simple 1 photo print, I eventually want to print multiple photos, and have like a slideshow.

Is this possible using joomla?

I also tried several other ways, but I had no luck. Is it possible to have ?

I just need a way through loop through images that are in a database, and print them out. Is there a good approach to this than what I am taking? Do I have to install plugins?

Comment: Joomla has it's own database class which you should use. There's no need to use `mysqli_*` and you should know that `mysql_*` is deprecated. You should also use Joomla JInput method instead of `$_GET`. Please refer to the Joomla documentation as your script needs a complete rewrite. If you want to have a slideshow, then develop a small module, not a separate PHP file

Comment: Thank you, I am totally new at this. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely wrong approach.

You have to develop a custom module to handle your slideshow task. [You could start here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module).

As for your current code you have to convert it to:

```
<?php

   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
   $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName('id'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__helloworld'))
            ->where('id = '. $db->Quote($params));
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $results = $db->loadObjectList();

   print_r($results);

?>
```

[Please check the full list of joomla database functions](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase).

[This part will help you how you could display your results](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObjectList.28.29).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for that information. I will try to do that approach!